# why is GnuPlot .tex to .pdf, large compared with raster images?

Tags: rules, gnuplot, file-size, pixelated

Raster scanned articles tend to be quite a bit larger than vector graphics based articles. In practice when I make a plot with gnuplot, the resulting pdf is large compared for what it displays. I look at the tex code it creates and draws the sine curve by multiputting `\rule` rectangles along sections of the graph. Why cant gnuplot sensibly emit say `\qbezier`'s?

Comment: It could, but it is simply the way it got programmed. Note that vector images hold more information than raster images. Usually every single data point is included, even if this level of detail doesn't make any difference for the naked eye.

Comment: I see that it could have gotten programmed like this historically, but you would need less bezier curves for staying in the same error margin as linear approximation.

Comment: I believe `\qbezier` would be problematic when plotting a function with jump discontinuities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plot functions rather than data files, decrease the number of sampling points, for example

```
set samples 50,50
```

(the deafult is 100, 100).  For 3D plots the parameter is `isosamples` (10, 10 by default).